# Discord.js doesn't see what emoji is reacted

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I have been struggling for the past couple of days on how to make this work.
I am trying to make it so when someone submits somebody it will ask for confirmation and then console.logs that. but it doesn't do anything when I press the check.

```
  // aca!evidence [URL] [ign/name]
  const checkChannel = client.channels.find("name", "testbotchannel");
  const ign = args[1];
  const link = args[2];
  const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '✅';

  if(!ign) {
    message.channel.send(`Please define a username`);
  } else if (!link) {
    message.channel.send(`Please define a URL`);
  } else {
    message.reply(`Thanks for submitting! We will review this asap!`)
    .then(msg => {
        msg.delete(10000)
      });
    checkChannel.send(`${message.author} submitted ${ign} (${link})`).then(async message => {
      await message.react("✅")
      await message.react("❎")
      message.awaitReactions(filter)
      .then(() => console.log(`Collected`))
      .catch(console.error)
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want instead of `.awaitReactions(...)` is [`.createReactionCollector(...)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector). Using this method, you can create an event that responds to each reaction on a message, using the 'collect' event.

Here's an example from the docs, fitted to your code after the line with `checkChannel.send(...)`

```
message.react('✅')
.then(mReaction => message.react('❎') )
.then(mReaction => {
    const collector = message.createReactionCollector(reactionFilter, { time: 15000 });
    collector.on('collect', r => console.log(`Collected ${r.emoji.name}`));
    collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`));
})
.catch(console.log);
```

P.S. I don't use the `await` library, but i'm sure you can adapt this for your needs. Let me know if you have any questions